# How to Predict with a Spark MLlib model trained in LibSVM format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I trained my model using a training data file that was in LibSVM format as described here http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-linear-methods.html.  Specifically I used this part

```
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

// Split data into training (60%) and test (40%).
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1)

// Run training algorithm to build the model
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
  .setNumClasses(10)
  .run(training)
```

but my question is how do you prepare your features for a model trained this way at prediction time?  The solution I came up with was to save an intermediate file in libsvm format (with dummy labels since I just want to predict) and load it using `MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile` then applying the result to the trained model to make a prediction.  However, this strategy is pretty inefficient and, in my system, this requires a very costly `collect()` call.  Is there any way of putting my data in the correct `LabeledPoint` format without first putting it in LibSVM format (which requires and intermediate file)?  I'm hoping I don't have to dig into the internals of `MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile` to figure out how a row in libSVM format is transformed into a `LabeledPoint` object.

PS: It looks like Spark's ML pipelines are a better way of doing this but I don't want to scrap all the work I've done so far and try that strategy if I can help it.

Comment: Actually, if you have the ability to create a LibSVM file, what prevents you from simply creating the vectors yourself and using them in the prediction? You already put your features into the filr, so they should already be prepared...?

Comment: @Shaido - yes I know how to put the features in the file - just didn't know how they are read from the file and transformed into the vector that is ultimately passed to the model.  I could dig into `MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile` to figure this out but I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that (but I ultimately did)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have finished training a model and only want to use it to predict, you do not need to have the data in `LabeledPoint` format. The only thing you need is a vector (either dense or sparse, see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/mllib-data-types.html) for more information) to make the prediction.

```
val prediction = model.predict(features)
```

Of course, it's also possible to convert to `LabeledPoint` as well, although not necessary. A small example:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (1, List(1.0,4.0,8.0)),
    (2, List(3.0,3.0,8.0)),
    (3, List(5.0,5.0,9.0))))

val rdd2 = rdd.map{ case(k, vs) => 
  LabeledPoint(k.toDouble, Vectors.dense(vs.toArray))
}
```

---

To convert between LibSVM format and Spark vectors is possible. In your LibSVM file each row have the following format:

```
<label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2> ... <indexN>:<valueN>
```

The indices where is the indices in the feature vector (same order for training and predicting). `MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile()` will create `LabeledPoint` following this, i.e. each`LabeledPoint` will look like this:

```
LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.sparse(N, Array(index1-1, index2-1, ...), Array(value1, value2, ...)))
```

A `SparseVector` is used in the example since the LibSVM file specifies both indices and values.

In the LibSVM, the indices starts at 1 while the more common convention (including for creating `SparseVector`) is to start at 0, hence, it is necissary to subtract 1 from the indices while converting from LibSVM format.

Following this, you can easily create the vectors yourself to do the prediction.

Comment: Yes but my question was more about how to create this vector.  The order of the elements of the feature vector matter.  If the order at prediction time is different from the order at training time then the prediction will be way off.  So how do you know that the order of the elements of the feature vector at prediction time are the same as what `MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile` produces from the libsvm file at training time?

Comment: @user1893354 Added additional information to the answer that should answer you question.

Comment: Yes that answers my question - but I was hoping Spark would have more of a built in solution for this.  Btw I dug into the code the code and the libsvm indexes start at 1 but as it is read, spark subtracts 1 from each so the indices in the final vector should actually be the libsvm index - 1 (you might want to add that to your answer)